# AAS - Invoke-ProcessPartition : Authentication failed

Tags: azure, powershell, ssas

I have a script to update my Azure Analysis Services running in a PowerShell Runbook. It has been running fine, but since the last week it started to run the error:

"Invoke-ProcessPartition : Authentication failed. Technical Details..." but seems to me a generic error... because this error doesn't occurs every day.

this is a part of my script:

[image]

this script updates tables and partitions and the error happens with the last parition in the script, but the line it's absolutely the same as the previous one, changing just the partition name otherwise this script should fails everyday.

Somone has faced this ploblem?

Comment: I am discussing the issue with some of our internal resources. It is possible the token is expiring as it only lasts an hour. Try adding ```Add-azureanalysisservicesaccount``` between calling ```Invoke-ProcessPartition``` to refresh the token.

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT yes, you're right! thank you

Comment: Awesome! Posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that as a dataset grows it takes longer and longer to process. When processing using Powershell the token created only lasts an hour. The refresh will complete successfully when the last process is started within the hour and fail when it goes over causing the intermittent failures.

By calling `Add-azureanalysisservicesaccount` in between processing requests it is possible to get a refreshed token that allows processing to continue.